# Python: How to use Escape character to solve "SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character"?

Tags: python, string, escaping, string-concatenation

**What I want to do:**

I want to print the following message as output:

> Hi "alias" your phone number is "1234567890" and your email ID is
>   "foo@bar.foo"

**Python Code**

```
name= "alias"
phone= "1234567890"
email="foo@bar.foo"

print("Hi " + name + " your phone number is " + phone + " and your email ID is " + email)
```

This gives me the following output:

> Hi alias your phone number is 1234567890 and your email ID is
>   foo@bar.foo

But here double quote (" ") is missing.

**What I tried to solve this:**

```
print("Hi " + \" name \" + " your phone number is " + \" phone \"+ " and your email ID is " + \" email \")
```

Comment: No, the escaped quotes need to be inside the non-escaped ones. But why don't you use single quotes for the surrounding ones, anyway?

Comment: `'Hi "{}" your phone number is "{}" and your email ID is "{}"'.format(name, phone, email)`

Comment: What are reasons for down vote? How do I know if the answer already exists ? I searched but I could not find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str.format`

**Ex:**

```
name= "alias"
phone= "1234567890"
email="foo@bar.foo"

result = 'Hi "{}" your phone number is {} and your email ID is {}'
print(result.format(name, phone, email))
```

---

or **f-string**(py3.6)

```
result = f'Hi "{name}" your phone number is {phone} and your email ID is {email}'
print(result)
```

Comment: This works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Use the two types of quotation mark:

```
print('Hi "' + name + '" your phone number is "' + phone + '" and your email ID is "' + email + '"')
```

Answer (score 0):

replace the print line with : 
`print("Hi " + "\""+ name +"\"" + " your phone number is " + "\""+ phone +"\""+ " and your email ID is " +"\""+ email+ "\"")`